# J2ee The requested resource is unavailable

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hello I know That this question has been asked before But unfortuanetly I didn t find among the answers proposed the one suitable for me 
I m still new  with J2ee lookin' forward for ur help
This is my code
        login.jsp

---

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"               "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>Login page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
    <form action="" method="post"/>
     <br> UserId: <input type="text" name="userId"/>
    <br> password<input type="password" name="password"/>
     <br><input type="submit"/>
    </form>
       </body>
   </html>
```

LoginServlet.java

```
    package org.islem.login;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import org.islem.login.service.LoginService; 


public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String userId,password;
    userId= request.getParameter("userId");
    System.out.println(userId);
    password= request.getParameter("password");

    LoginService loginService= new LoginService();
    boolean result= loginService.authenticate(userId, password);
    if (result)
    {
        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        return;
    }   

}
```

}

LoginService.java

```
    package org.islem.login.service;

 public class LoginService { 
   public boolean authenticate (String userId,String password)
  {
     if (password ==null || password.trim() =="") {
     return false;
     }
     else return true;

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form action is empty, you should fill it your servlet name in your case it should be like:

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post"/>
```

I assume you already define your servlet name at your web.xml

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify some controller name within the action:

```
<form action="LoginServlet " method="post"/>
     <br> UserId: <input type="text" name="userId"/>
     <br> password<input type="password" name="password"/>
     <br> <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Remember: This action specifies where the data submitted by the form will be received.